# Can you really have the International Star Registry name a star that you can easily see in an amateur telescope, like in A Walk to Remember?

Tags: realism, a-walk-to-remember

In *A Walk to Remember*, there is a scene where Landon asks Jamie to look at a star in her telescope, then reveals that he named it after her.

> Landon: Can you find this star right here?
>
> Jamie: Sure. [She looks at the map and adjusts the telescope and finds it pretty quickly] So, why am I looking for this star?
>
> Landon: Because I had it named after you. [Shows a rolled up piece of paper] See? It's official. It's from the International Star Registry. [Jamie comes over and excitedly looks at it]
>
> Jamie: It's wonderful. [whispers] I love you.

As he says, it's from the [International Star Registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Star_Registry), which despite what Landon says, [is not official at all](http://www.wired.com/2001/12/buy-a-star-but-its-not-yours/). But since the ISR has been around from 1979, wouldn't the stars that are easily seen with an amateur telescope have been given names ages ago (or even given official names back when telescopes were first used for astronomy)?

<sub>*In researching this question, I found that [the original script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/A_Walk_to_Remember.pdf) had Landon instead say "I know it's not an official designation—" and not mention the ISR. Pity that the final version made him seem like he got duped into thinking that the ISR gave official names to stars.*</sub>

Comment: There are a *lot* of stars that can be seen with a basic telescope. Estimates of how many can be seen by the naked eye in a good location vary but might be as many as 9-10,000.  That said, the most difficult to believe part of this is not that the star would be already named - but that it can be found that quickly.

Comment: The ISR is sort of like the Continental Kennel Club.  They will do whatever you want for $50.  I'm fairly certain that they've never told anyone, "Oh, I'm sorry.  That star has already been named after someone."

Comment: Cue... *"Space is big"* quote.

Comment: There are more stars  in heaven, Thunderforge, Than are dreamt of in your philosophy.

Comment: Fun question, but barely movie-related. (But no thumbs down from me! I'm just saying it's not much about movies!)

Comment: @BrettFromLA Should I have this moved to another SE site?

Comment: @Thunderforge It seems more like a question related to ... business? Like the legitimacy of that business, maybe? I think the question is, "What is the business model of International Star Registry? Do they sell the same stars multiple times? Does anyone respect / use the names they have unofficially 'given' to stars?"

Comment: @iandotkelly: Time compression is a well established principle in cinematography. The realistic time it would take would notably detract from the flow of the scene. The most obvious example are phone calls, where the caller (unheard by the viewer) did not get enough time to explain the complicated message that the actor (seen by the viewer) is now informed of.